# Set variable as global

Tags: jmeter-plugins

Hi I am storing tokenid using webdriver sampler .

```
var foo = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('ngStorage-jwtToken');")       
var obj = JSON.parse(foo);
vars.put("auth",obj.oauth_token)
WDS.log.info(vars.get('auth'))
```

Need to set this as global , so that I can put this tokenid in HTTP Header Manager in all other threads.

Answer (score 0):

To add value to all threads you need to save it as JMeter Property.

In Webdriver sampler use `WDS.props`:

```
WDS.props.put("auth", obj.oauth_token);
```

> # *WDS.props* - JMeterProperties (class [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)) - e.g.
>   props.get("START.HMS"); props.put("PROP1","1234");

If it doesn't work, use [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of Webdriver sampler and copy auth variable to property using:

```
props.put("auth", vars.get("auth"));
```

Then you can get JMeter propery value using `${__P(auth)}` or `props.get("auth")`